# How to Recreate the Last State of an App the Next Time it is Launched?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have 2 views. When I'm on the 1st view, I have a textfield. I enter some text in the textfield. I exit the app, launch some another application and then return to my application. I want to maintain state of the textfield and that view. Likewise, if I quit with the 2nd view active, when I return to the app I need to return the view to the state it was in when the app quit.

How do I save the information about the state of my app when it last quit so I can recreate it upon the next launch?

Comment: 16 questions in two months, and *not one* of them got an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NSUserDefaults` to write the value and selected view index to the user's preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [DrillDownSave](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/DrillDownSave/index.html) sample may be helpful